# Change python string to a list

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

So I have ended up with a string after parsing some javascript function on an HTML page. The string is as follows:

```
a = '[{"arjun":1,"samir":2},{"ryan":3, "jarret": 9}]'
```

As is evident, the string is a list of dicts in essence.How do I convert it to a python list?

Comment: You have JSON data (JSON is a narrow subset of Javascript). Just decode this with `json.loads()`.

Comment: ok..i am a bit embarrassed now..i knew this had to be really simple..